# Why is my textview showing "0:0null" when it should be showing "6:00 am"?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

So I need to be able to take text from an EditText on another activity, so I used intent to send that info. I tested the app, and inputted "6:00 am", but "0:0null" is what is being displayed on the textview. I don't know if the issue is the edittext isn't getting the right info, or if it isn't being sent over. Thank you in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
super.onResume();
final ToggleButton button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
final LinearLayout alarmLayout=findViewById(R.id.alarmLayout);
alarmLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
Bundle b =this.getIntent().getExtras();
if (b!=null) {
    h = b.getInt("h");
    m = b.getInt("m");
    ampm = b.getString("ampm");
}
if (bundle!=null) {
    intervalMinute = bundle.getInt("min");
}
alarmLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
final TextView textView =findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
textView.setTextSize(28);
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
textView.setText(h + ":" + m + ampm);
Intent i = getIntent();
final String value = i.getStringExtra("buttonStatus");
if (value!=null&&value.equals("Visible")) {
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    alarmLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

NewAlarm.java

```
EditText editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
EditText editText2=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText editText4=findViewById(R.id.editText4);
String hou=editText.getText().toString();
int h=Integer.parseInt(hou);
String min=editText2.getText().toString();
int m=Integer.parseInt(min);
String ampm=editText4.getText().toString();
Intent myIntent=new Intent(v.getContext(),alarmFrequency.class);
Intent intent=new Intent(NewAlarm.this,MainActivity.class);
b =new Bundle();
b.putInt("h",h);
b.putInt("m",m);
b.putString("ampm",ampm);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
    }
});
```

There are no errors, not even NullPointerExceptions, but the code isn't quite doing what I want it to do.

Comment: why do you put `ampm` and `m`, `h` into intent different ways?

Comment: I was getting errors when I put m,h in the same intent so I used b.putInt().

Comment: so now you are getting problems putting ampm in the same intent... Doesn't this means you should try the same?